# Datanucleus enhancer not working with appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jpa, datanucleus

At the moment I am working on a webapplication written in Java, using Spring, JPA, AppEngine and Datanucleus. It all worked well, until last week when all of a sudden nothing would compile anymore (not even older versions on SVN).

The versions I am using at the moment are:

- datanucleus: 3.2.5
- appengine: 1.8.1
- datanucleus-appengine: 2.1.2
- datanucleus-jpa: 2.1.8
- datanucleus-api-jpa: 3.3.0-m1
- datanucleus-maven-plugin: 3.3.0-m1

Together with some other dependencies, however I think the ones in the list are the most important ones. Everything is compiled using Maven. When I run `maven clean install` or `maven datanucleus:enhance` the enhancer crashes:

```
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR]  Standard error from the DataNucleus tool + org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer :
[ERROR] --------------------
[ERROR] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.getOMFContext()Lorg/datanucleus/OMFContext;
        at org.datanucleus.jpa.metadata.JPAAnnotationReader.processClassAnnotations(JPAAnnotationReader.java:199)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:126)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:171)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2757)
        at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadPersistenceUnit(MetaDataManager.java:1015)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:796)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:513)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1281)

[ERROR] --------------------
```

It also gives some other errors:

```
Extension Point "org.datanucleus.implementation_creator" not registered, but plugin "org.datanucleus.enhancer" defined in file:/D:/FBLAAUW/.m2/repository/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-enhancer/3.1.1/datanucleus-enhancer-3.1.1.jar refers to it.
```

and several of the following errors (approx 100)

```
ERROR DataNucleus.Persistence  - User-defined type mapping class "org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Collection" was not found. Please check the mapping file class specifications and your CLASSPATH. The class must be in the CLASSPATH.
```

I am using JRE 1.7, but I also tried using JRE 1.6 (which also did not work). My guess is that the used versions are not compliant with each other, but I am not sure. Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest you sort out the versions of jars being used. [This page](https://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/Compatibility) states the compatibility of Googles "datanucleus-appengine" with DataNucleus project jars

Comment: Thank you DataNucleus, It was indeed the datanucleus-appengine jar which was interfering with the rest. The latest version of datanucleus-appengine is not yet on the maven repository, and therefore an older version of all other dependencies should be used. Thank you for the link! Using version 3.1.1 for datanucleus solved my problem.